# multiplying in while loop with prefix increment

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prefix

I'm a newbie in Javascript and I need to learn how this simple code that I just saw somewhere in the internet works:

```
var f = 1;
var i = 2;

while(++i<5) {
    f*=i;
}

console.log(f);
```

Can anybody help me understand how this loop works?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Answer (score 3):

Check comments to understand it:

```
var f = 1;
var i = 2;

while(++i<5) { //will increment first and then check if the incremented value is less than 5

    f*=i; //can also be written as f = f*i
}

console.log(f);
```

**First iteration:**: while (3<5) it will make f = 1*3 which is 3

**Second iteration:**: while (4<5) it will make f = 3*4 which is 12

**Third iteration:**: while (5<5) which is false so loop will stop

Comment: My pleasure :) You can mark the answer as correct in case it clarified your doubt.

Answer (score 2):

A less cryptic `while` loop that does the same thing would be:

```js
var f = 1;
var i = 2;

++i;                // increment i
while (i < 5) {     // loop while i is less than 5
  f = f * i;        // assign f * i to f. aka "scale f by i"
  ++i;              // increment i
}

console.log("i:", i, "f:", f);
```

Here's a table

```
Iteration    |   i   |   f
------------------------------
Before loop  |   3   |   1
After 1st    |   4   |   3
After 2nd    |   5   |  12
```

And it exits after the 2nd iteration because 5 is not less than 5.

Answer (score 1):

The while loop is executed every time when, the expression within the braces is truthy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Hence when `i` is less then `5`, an iteration is executed. But `++` before `i` might be tricky. Prefix is added before the execution, hence, this loop will be iterated with `i=2+1=3` and `i=3+1=4`.